# footnote with smaller characters

Tags: plain-tex, font-encodings

How can I write a footnote with smaller characters? How can I write a formula in a footnote, with the same character size (fonts) as the main text of the footnote?

Example:

```
\footnote{${}^1$}%
{\font\bigrm = cmr8 scaled \magstephalf {%
 {\bigrm This gauge is always used .....etc....etc., %
  so that we can write $h_{ij,j}\ (=h_{ij}k_j)\ =0$.%
}}}
```

The font of the footnote is OK, but everything between `$...$` has the same font/dimension as the main text, which is very unpleasant.

Comment: usually, something like this is defined in the document class, but not all document classes are defined in the same way.  so it's necessary to know what document class you're using in order to give an intelligent answer.  actually, a small compilable example would be even more helpful.

Comment: To get some help, you should be more specific regarding the expected output

Comment: OK - here is an example:\footnote{${}^1$}{\font\bigrm = cmr8 scaled \magstephalf {{\bigrm This gauge is always used .....etc....etc., so that we can write $h_{ij,j}\ (=h_{ij}k_j)\ =0$.}}} The font of the footnote is OK, but everything between $...$ has the same font/dimension as the main text, which is very unpleasant. Thank  you/

Comment: plain tex is just a small format of "basic macros" for examples in the texbook, a format such as latex or context that's designed for document production would have more complete support for font size changes.

Answer (score 1):

Plain TeX has no provision for changing font size in footnotes and one has to do some manual work for it.

Here's an example, but you might want to look at some higher level macro package such as OPmac (compatible with traditional plain TeX).

```
% borrow some code from manmac.tex
\catcode`@=11

\font\eightrm=cmr8 \font\sixrm=cmr6 %\font\fiverm=cmr5
\font\eighti=cmmi8 \font\sixi=cmmi6 %\font\fivei=cmmi5
\font\eightex=cmex8 \font\sixex=cmex7 at 6pt \font\fivex=cmex7 at 5pt
\font\eightsy=cmsy8 \font\sixsy=cmsy6 %\font\fivesy=cmsy5
\font\eightbf=cmbx8 \font\sixbf=cmbx6 %\font\fivebf=cmbx5
\font\eightsl=cmsl8
\font\eightit=cmti8
\font\eighttt=cmtt8
\font\sevenex=cmex7

\def\footnote#1{\edef\@sf{\spacefactor\the\spacefactor}#1\@sf
      \insert\footins\bgroup\eightpoint
      \interlinepenalty100 \let\par=\endgraf
        \leftskip=\z@skip \rightskip=\z@skip
        \splittopskip=10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt \floatingpenalty=20000
        \smallskip\item{#1}\bgroup\strut\aftergroup\@foot\let\next}
\skip\footins=12pt plus 2pt minus 4pt % space added when footnote is present
%\count\footins=1000 % footnote magnification factor (1 to 1)
\dimen\footins=30pc % maximum footnotes per page

\newskip\ttglue
\def\tenpoint{\def\rm{\fam0\tenrm}%
  \textfont0=\tenrm \scriptfont0=\sevenrm \scriptscriptfont0=\fiverm
  \textfont1=\teni \scriptfont1=\seveni \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
  \textfont2=\tensy \scriptfont2=\sevensy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
  \textfont3=\tenex \scriptfont3=\sevenex \scriptscriptfont3=\fivex
  \def\it{\fam\itfam\tenit}%
  \textfont\itfam=\tenit
  \def\sl{\fam\slfam\tensl}%
  \textfont\slfam=\tensl
  \def\bf{\fam\bffam\tenbf}%
  \textfont\bffam=\tenbf \scriptfont\bffam=\sevenbf
   \scriptscriptfont\bffam=\fivebf
  \def\tt{\fam\ttfam\tentt}%
  \textfont\ttfam=\tentt
  \tt \ttglue=.5em plus.25em minus.15em
  \normalbaselineskip=12pt
  \def\MF{{\manual META}\-{\manual FONT}}%
  \let\sc=\eightrm
  \let\big=\tenbig
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height8.5pt depth3.5pt width\z@}%
  \normalbaselines\rm}

\def\eightpoint{\def\rm{\fam0\eightrm}%
  \textfont0=\eightrm \scriptfont0=\sixrm \scriptscriptfont0=\fiverm
  \textfont1=\eighti \scriptfont1=\sixi \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
  \textfont2=\eightsy \scriptfont2=\sixsy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
  \textfont3=\eightex \scriptfont3=\sixex \scriptscriptfont3=\fivex
  \def\it{\fam\itfam\eightit}%
  \textfont\itfam=\eightit
  \def\sl{\fam\slfam\eightsl}%
  \textfont\slfam=\eightsl
  \def\bf{\fam\bffam\eightbf}%
  \textfont\bffam=\eightbf \scriptfont\bffam=\sixbf
   \scriptscriptfont\bffam=\fivebf
  \def\tt{\fam\ttfam\eighttt}%
  \textfont\ttfam=\eighttt
  \tt \ttglue=.5em plus.25em minus.15em
  \normalbaselineskip=9pt
  \def\MF{{\manual opqr}\-{\manual stuq}}%
  \let\sc=\sixrm
  \let\big=\eightbig
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height7pt depth2pt width\z@}%
  \normalbaselines\rm}

\tenpoint
\catcode`@=12

\vsize=2cm % just for the example

Some text just to show the effect\footnote{${}^1$}{This gauge is always used so 
  that we can write $h_{ij,j}\ (=h_{ij}k_j)\ =0$.}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Fontch or varisize come to mind; even plnfss can do it, if properly used; but @wipet also promotes his own fss (ofs) for roughly this purpose, which doesn't require csplain, as opmac does.

Comment: Ah, bravo Figaro!
Bravo, bravissimo!
Fortunatissimo per verità!

Comment: Mille grazie, "egreg"

Comment: @erreka “Borrow some code from `manmac.tex`”. Spot the changes. `;-)`

Comment: Please, help me again, How can I compose "\o" in Plain TeX, if "\def\o{\over}" is already in use? Friendly thanks!

Comment: @ToniMarian Plain TeX does `\chardef\o="1C`

Comment: Sorry, it does not work! It is possible to be out of my understanding. The command   \chardef\o="1C  does not change anything.

Comment: @ToniMarian Just replace `\o` in the definition with the macro you want to stand for ø: `\chardef\tonio="1C`. Of course the best solution is *not* doing `\def\o{\over}` that saves almost nothing.

Comment: Dear Sir: Here is the detailed situation. I have used "\def\c{\over}" on about 500 pages and now, just for once, I have met a name of some scientist written with "\c" (i.e. small o slash). Therefore, my question is:

Comment: how can I write \o just for once, without changing command "\def\o{\over}" ? (Sorry, it is "o", not "c")

Comment: @ToniMarian `sci\char"1C\relax ntist` will print `sciøntist`; you planned badly when decided to use `\o` for `\over`.

Comment: Evrika! You bare great! It is exactly what I wanted (and I did not know how to use it). Indeed, M\char"1C\relax ller prints Moller (correctly). The command \def\c{\over} is used only between $...$, e.g. $x\o y=z$.

Comment: @ToniMarian You *could* do `\def\o{\relax\ifmmode\over\else\char"1C\relax\fi}`. Of course the best is *not* using `\o` as a shorthand for `\over`.

Comment: Thank you again. This time the problem is more complicated: how can I insert graphs in formulas? How can I show you a sample? My real name is Ioan Merches, PhD, emeritus professor; email: merches@uaic.ro.

Comment: @ToniMarian Please, ask a new question.

Comment: O.K. Something like this: +(..formula..) (graph - e.g. a Feynman) + (...formula,,,) (graph)

Comment: O.K. Something like this: +(..formula..) (graph - e.g. a Feynman diagram)) + (...formula,,,) (graph) (formula)\next similar raw, etc. - the graphs being of the same size (with) as the rest of the formula.